# Table has horizontal scrollbar even when there is no overflow

Tags: html, css, html-table, material-ui, overflow

I have a table made with Material UI (v4) components that is displaying a horizontal scrollbar even when there is no additional content to scroll to. I am using Chrome with MacOS. I have a container with the following styles:

```
container: {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 30%);
    overflow-x: auto;
    border-radius: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
```

It is wrapped around a table with the following styles:

```
table: {
    min-width: 800px;
    background: #fff;
}
```

Despite setting `overflow-x` to `auto`, there is a scrollbar at the bottom, no matter how large I make the viewport, and no matter how large or small I set the `min-width`. The container, and all the elements inside it, are all the same number of pixels wide according to Chrome dev tools, so it's not like the contents of the table are exceeding the width of the container.

Please note, setting `overflow-x` to `hidden` is *not* an option, as I do want the scrollbar to show up in the event that the contents of the table exceed the width of the viewport.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: did yiu check the css values in your browser debugger ?

Comment: Hi Buddy,
Is it possible to share a screenshot of the issue? It will help me to understand.

Comment: @ArkaBhattacharjee Thank you for the response. I have a screenshot of the table here: [Imgur link](https://imgur.com/a/8Gxl8sa)